# Searching for one of two complexish regex patterns in Python without creating submatches

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing some TV episodes that have been transcribed by different people, meaning I need to search for a variety of formats. For example, new scenes are indicated one of two ways:

`[A coffee shop]`

or

`INT. Coffee shop - NIGHT`

Right now, I match this with the following regex in Python:

```
re.findall("(^\[(.+?)\]$)|(^[INTEXT]{3}\. .+?$)", text)
```

where "text" is the text of the entire script (hence using `findall`). This always appears on its own line, hence the `^$`

This gives me something like: `(None, None, "INT. Coffee Shop - NIGHT")` for example.

**My question:** How do you construct a regex to search for one of two complex patterns, using the `|` notation, without *also* creating submatches that you don't really want? Or is there a better way?

Many thanks.

**UPDATE**: I had overlooked the idea of non-capturing groups. I can accomplish what I want with:

```
"(?:^\[.+?\]$)|(?:^[INTEX]{3}\. .+?$)"
```

However, this raises a new question. I don't actually want the brackets or the INT/EXT in the scenes, just the location. I thought that I could use actual groups within the none-capturing groups, but I'm still getting those blank matches for the other expression, like so:

```
import re

pattern = "(?:^\[(.+?)\]$)|(?:^[INTEX]{3}\. (.+?)$)"

examples = [                                                                                                                                                                     
    "[coffee shop]",                                                                                                                                                                 
    "INT. COFFEE SHOP - DAY",                                                                                                                                                        
    "EXT. FIELD - NIGHT",                                                                                                                                                            
    "[Hugh's aparment]"
]

for example in examples:
    print re.findall(pattern, example)


'''
[('coffee shop', '')]
[('', 'COFFEE SHOP - DAY')]
[('', 'FIELD - NIGHT')]
[("Hugh's aparment", '')]
'''
```

I can just `join()` them, but is there a better way?

Comment: Your current regex is not even valid. The `)` is unbalanced.

Comment: @nhahtdh I fixed that for him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the limited examples you've provided, how about using assertions for the brackets:

```
re.findall("((?<=^\[)[^[\]]+(?=\]$)|^[INTEXT]{3}\. .+?$)", text)
```

Comment: @JanneKarila No, I didn't  ;)  Though I will admit that escaping the brackets inside of a character class is more intuitive.

Comment: @JanneKarila You're correct. I tested with the test string without the brackets--forgot to check the other one. Corrected. Had I just swapped the `[` and the `]`, then it would have been fine (i.e. no escaping necessary).

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! (I like @nneonneo's suggestion too for sake of simplicity and readability.)

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off just using two expressions.

```
patterns = [r'^\[(.+?)\]$', r'^(?:INT|EXT)\. (.+?)$']

for example in examples:
    print re.findall(patterns[0], example) or re.findall(patterns[1], example)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want:

```
(?m)^(?=(?:\[|[INTEX]{3}\.\s+)([^\]\r\n]+))(?:\[\1\]|[INTEX]{3}\. \1)$
```

First the lookahead peeks at the text of the scene marker, capturing it in group #1.  Then the rest of the regex goes ahead and consumes the whole line containing the marker.  Although now I think about it, you don't really have to consume anything.  This works, too:

```
result = re.findall(r"(?m)^(?=(?:\[|[INTEX]{3}\.\s+)([^\]\r\n]+))", subject)
```

The marker text is still captured in group #1, so it still gets added to the result of `findall()`.  Then again, I don't see why you would want to use `findall()` here.  If you're trying to normalize the scene markers by replacing them in place, you'll have to use the consuming version of the regex.

Also, notice the `(?m)`.  In your examples you always apply the regex to the scene markers in isolation.  To pluck them out of the whole script, you have to set the `MULTILINE` flag, turning `^` and `$` into line anchors.